# div:before appearing in front of the block

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a background line to my score box but for some reason `div::before` is not hiding behind in this case. [You can view it live here](http://www.aslanyurek.com/en/game/1573566693)

```
    .game-center-result .score h1 {
    font-size: 56px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0;
    border: 2px solid #45464f;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 127px;
    height: 127px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    line-height: 131px;
    background: #30313b;
}
.game-center-result .score h1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #44454d;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[[image]]

Comment: I would suggest asking this question on https://stackoverflow.com/, this site is for WordPress and your question is about CSS.  Its a z-index issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032856/is-it-possible-to-set-the-stacking-order-of-pseudo-elements-below-their-parent-e

Answer (score 0):

Despite the name, `:before` doesn't actually set the layering position of elements, that's set via [`z-index`](https://bytutorial.com/tutorials/css/css-z-index). To position your :before element behind the H1 text, you need to add

```
z-index: -1;
```

to the :before element, like so:

```
.game-center-result .score h1:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #44454d;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:-1;
}
```